# How to get cookies from HTTP response performed via Endpoint method?

Tags: java, cookies, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to create an endpoint method, which is supposed to log me in to a different system and return the authorization cookie's value for further use in my application. Even though my method successfully logs me to the system (I checked the response data), i cannot retrieve the cookie from header files of the response. This is the bean's method called from endpoint method.

```
public String login (String password, String name) {
    String urlParameters = "destination=" + MAILBOX_URL_SUFFIX + "&credential_0=" + name +
        "&credential_1=" + password + "&login=Prihl%E1si%BB+sa";

URL url = null;
// *****************  login  ***********************
try {
    URI uri = new URI("https", "is.stuba.sk", "/system/login.pl", null);
    url = uri.toURL();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpURLConnection con = null;

try {
    con =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

appendRequestHeader(con);

//Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = null;

try {
    wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);

    wr.flush();
    wr.close();


    con.connect();
    con.getInputStream();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String cookie = "default";
String headerName=null;
for (int i=1; (headerName = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
    cookie.concat(con.getHeaderField(i));
}
return cookie;
}
```

EDIT: the method returns "default" all the time, none Set-Cookie, nor the other cookies

Before, when i was not running the method from server-side the code started with

```
        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

... and instead of using con.headerField i used this, to successfully get my cookie.

```
return manager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue();
```

However CookieManager is blacklisted for Google Cloud Endpoints and i cannot retrieve the cookie any other way :(

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I assume your call to your service is a POST. If I were you, I would use a tool like postman to make sure you get the cookie in the header of the response. If the cookie is in the http header of the response, there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to get it.